# IE 11 Enhanced Protection Mode doesn't stay off

Tags: windows-10, internet-explorer

My work place has an external website (trusted) which requires *Enhanced* Protection Mode in IE 11 to be turned off to function correctly, however I can't seem to turn it off.

After going into Tools -> Internet Settings -> Advanced dialog, scrolling down to the Security sub-section, to uncheck Enhanced Protection Mode, and restarting the PC, it is rechecked upon getting back into Windows.

I have confirmed:

- Unchecking and then reopening the dialog box prior to restarting shows it unchecked.
- As we make use of GPO's: `rsop.msc` shows no subsection `Advanced page` under User Configuration (or Computer Configuration) -> Administrative Templates -> Windows Components -> Internet Explorer -> Internet Control Panel
- Turning off both Protected mode in the internet zone, and Enhanced Protected Mode and rebooting PC makes no difference
- Google'ng doesn't seem to result in any other circumstances this would happen

Why is Enhanced Protection Mode presumably being turned on again at startup?

Comment: You might post your OS for a better answer.Is it a work computer or a home computer?

Comment: [Moab](https://superuser.com/users/40928), thanks. Done.